# Visual Studio Community 2015 Fatal Error

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2015

[image]

I've tried:

- uninstalling VS 2015 redistributables
- both the web installer and the ISO
- Deleting everything in %temp%
- Uninstalling the failed installs and deleting their folders
- Restarting a dozen times
- Already have all windows 7 updates

The error log:

```
[0D24:07E0][2016-06-09T23:57:04]i301: Applying execute package: vs_devenvLP, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\{173D2989-6B09-3A90-8819-A53E43F99818}v14.0.23107\packages\vs_devenvLP\vs_devenvLP.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" VSEXTUI="1"'
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: MUX:  ExecuteError: Package (vs_devenvLP) failed: Error Message Id: 2902 ErrorMessage: The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902. 
[0D24:07E0][2016-06-09T23:57:05]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to install MSI package.
[0D24:07E0][2016-06-09T23:57:05]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to configure per-machine MSI package.
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: MUX:  Installation size in bytes for package: vs_devenvLP MaxAppDrive: 0  MaxSysDrive: 413696  AppDrive: 0  SysDrive: 131072
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: MUX:  Return Code:0x80070643 Msi Messages:The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902.  Result Detail:0 Restart:None
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: MUX:  Set Result: Return Code=-2147023293 (0x80070643), Error Message=The installer has encountered an unexpected error installing this package. This may indicate a problem with this package. The error code is 2902. , Result Detail=, Vital=True, Package Action=Install, Package Id=vs_devenvLP
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: Setting string variable 'BundleResult' to value '1603'
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i319: Applied execute package: vs_devenvLP, result: 0x80070643, restart: None
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]e000: Error 0x80070643: Failed to execute MSI package.
[1380:0C44][2016-06-09T23:57:05]i000: MUX:  ExecutePackageBegin PackageId: vs_devenvLP
```

Any ideas or solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was failing to get access to certain folders such as the start menu and some system folders.

I recursively took ownership of all folders and set their permissions to full access and it was able to install.

Comment: like where?
how do reqursively THAT?

Answer (score 0):

The most of the time it means that your package was corrupted.

You should verify you have corrupted package or not. Please use FCIV.exe http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841290 to verify hash of ISO. Any discrepancy would indicate that the file was corrupted.

The SHA-1 value for VS community is "BAAD3CEBAB7A5834D8F78F7D02E4880C010F3BA9".

If your SHA-1 value is incorrupted, it means that your package is corrupted, you should re-download and reinstall it. E.g. from here: http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/C/0BC321A4-013F-479C-84E6-4A2F90B11269/vs2015.com_enu.iso

Or if you don't want to take any steps you just need to reinstall Windows. It will help.